# I can not add 'total' as word under year column

Tags: sql

I need to add total wood in overall total for each column. It does not work because "total" is character and cannot be placed in a numeric variable. Below is the code i am using:

```
proc sql;
 create table final as
     select year,
            count(distinct id) as total_persons,
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '20-25' then id end) as tot_20_25, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '25-30' then id end) as tot_25_30, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '30-35' then id end) as tot_30_35 
     from old_table
     group by year
     union all
     select 'Total',/*Here is line error, if i leave there just quotes works but it is not appropriate.*/
            count(distinct id) as total_persons,
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '20-25' then id end) as tot_20_25, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '25-30' then id end) as tot_25_30, 
            count(distinct case when age_cat = '30-35' then id end) as tot_30_35 
     from old_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type inconsistency.  In SQL, you would fix this by converting the `year` to a string:

```
cast(year as varchar(255))
```

In `proc sql`, you can use `put`:

```
put(year, 15.)
```

Answer (score 0):

First column in first query year is numeric value but first column if second query 'total' is not numeric, convert year to varchar
CONVERT(varchar, year)